# How to read xml file in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I am very new to grails and perhaps it would be the most simplest of questions that I am asking.
I am creating a very simple application for self-learning where I created a login page. On successful login,the xml file should be read and the output should be displayed. Can anyone please illustrate this with a sample example. Also please tell what should be the folder location for the xml file?Below is my code:
**UserController.groovy**

```
class UserController {

    def index = { }

    def login = {
        def user = User.findWhere(username:params['username'],
                                  password:params['password'])
                                  session.user = user
        if (user) {     
            redirect(action:display)
        }
        else {
             redirect(url:"http://localhost:8080/simple-login/")
        }
    }
    def display = {
        def stream = getClass().classLoader.getResourceAsStream("grails-app/conf/sample.xml")
        return [data: XML.parse(stream)]
    }

}
```

**myxml.gsp**

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Please find the  details below:</p>
    <p>${data}</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

**URLMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/user/login" (controller: "user" ,action: "login")
        "/user/display"(controller:"user" ,action:"display")

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }

}
```

Now that I already have index.gsp as the first page that appears when user login, is it possible to specify more than one view in URLMappings? Also as suggested in one of the replies, if I have to define an action named "myxml" and direct to a url such as "/controller"/myxml where would that be? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Here I am placing my xml files under `webapp/xmls/` directory, and parsing `abc.xml` file

```
def parse ( ) {
  // Getting context path here
  def webRootDir = sch.servletContext.getRealPath ("/")

  // Create a new file instance
  def f = new File (webRootDir + "/xmls/" + "abc.xml")

  // Parxing XML file here
  def items = new XmlParser ( ).parseText( f.text )

  // iterating through XML blocks here
  items.question.each {
        // Creating domain class object to save in DB
    def question = new Question ( )
    def node = it
    question.with {
    qtext = node.qtext.text()
    answer = node.answer.text()
    if (!hasErrors() && save(flush: true)) {
      log.info "mcq saved successfully"
    } else
    errors.allErrors.each {
          err->
              log.error err.getField() + ": "
              log.error err.getRejectedValue() + ": " + err.code
    }
   }
 }
}
```

This is the sample XML (abc.xml) file:

```
<qns>
  <question id="q1">
    <qtext> First letter of alphabet is?</qtext>
    <answer>A<answer>
  </question>

  <question id="q2">
    <qtext> Second letter of alphabet is?</qtext>
    <answer>A<answer>
  </question>
  .
  .
  .
  .
</qns>
```

Hope this will help ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick sample.

**Controller**

```
def index = {
  def stream = getClass().classLoader.getResourceAsStream("grails-app/conf/my-file.xml")
  return [data: XML.parse(stream)]
}
```

**View** (index.gsp)

```
<html>
...
<body>
  <p>${data}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just create an action myxml and a view myxml.gsp, then go to the url /"controller"/myxml

Comment: 1. XML.parse() only takes a String or a HttpServletRequest, you want eg. XML.parse(stream, "UTF-8") or whatever encoding you're using.


2. If my-file.xml is in your "grails-app/conf" directory, you only need .getResourceAsStream("my-file.xml")